# Browser window size else then in template

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, figma

In Figma(not really matter where) template has 1920px width. I want to create a page from it, but in the browser, the page has 1903px. Some of my elements do not fit and wrap down (when using flex-wrap e.g) due to it. So the question is, how to make it properly?

EDIT: On this
[screen with clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXOL7.png)  I tried to add fourth square but there no space so it wrapped to the bottom. Browser width is 1903px, within template I do from is 1920px. How other people do in situations like this, how it must be done to make it responsive on all pc screens?

Comment: Is there any padding or margin? Please provide us some code for clarity.

Comment: Please take a look, I updated my question. I have paddings only in my container, 160px left and right. In total the width of my browser screen is 1903px but what I must do is 1920px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it inside container like in bootstrap you can specify to which screen only it can wrap
For example:
.container-xl will only wrap your content inside container on xLarge screen only.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to tackle this problem.  The first would be something along the lines of Rashidtvmr's answer.  You can use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) in your project and simply follow their guide for creating a [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) in your project.  With bootstrap, you can solve your issue with something like the below code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where a grid system is created of 12 columns and you can specify how many an element should take up with col-2, col-3, col-4, etc.  If you want them all to be the same width over all screens, then just specify each as col and bootstrap will take care of the rest.

If you can't or don't want to use Bootstrap, the next solution would be to create your own grid system using CSS.  Without an example of your code, it's hard to specify exactly how it should look but following this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) should help you out.